# Deviantart 403 error. Сайт открывается только через закладки

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, vpn, http-status-code-403

Возможно, вы знаете, с определённого времени сайт DeviantArt выдаёт ошибку 403 для многих VPN, я не использовать VPN не могу, так как мой провайдер блокирует некоторые серверы этого сайта, из-за чего пропадают изображения. Ранее всё было отлично с Hola VPN, но теперь и тут 403 тоже.

Однако, в связи с этим, появилась непонятная ситуация. Почему-то, если использовать проблемный VPN, то, через закладки, этот сайт вполне открывается. То есть, если я просто вставляю адрес в адресную строку, то получаю ошибку 403, но если я делаю закладку с этой ссылкой и нажимаю на эту закладку, то сайт открывается.

Кто-нибудь знает, как это работает? Можно ли перенести это на весь браузер, чтобы так было со всеми ссылками? Браузер Chrome, кэш чистый, других расширений нет.